# Get value of Select2 custom tag using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Using Select2, I have a selectBox that I want users to be able to type out their own custom tags to (just like stackoverflow's question tagging system).  Here's what I'm working with currently:

Javascript:

```
$(".custom").select2({tags: true, tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']})
var $customSelect = $(".custom");
$customSelect.on("Select2:select", function(e) {
    console.log("Custom Selection: " + e.params.data);
});
```

HTML:

```
<select class="selectBox custom" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

The selectBox in the HTML has no options because I want users to define them themselves by typing in tags.  The javascript worked fine for my non-custom selectBoxes but can't seem to grab any data for my custom ones.

Comment: Holy crap the casing was the problem! Thanks and sorry I'm dumb!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are catching the wrong event.

Select2 triggers all events using the lowercase name, so you should be catching `select2:select`, **not** `Select2:select`.